# How do I know which exchanges are serious actors?

Tags: exchanges, trust

- How do I find bitcoin exchanges?
- How do I know if the exchanges can be trusted?

Comment: The question here is **how to evaluate and pick an exchange** to do business with. Answers that ignore the question and instead recommend specific services will be removed as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding Bitcoin exchanges, check here (exchanges are ordered by volume):
https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/markets/USD

There are two types of Bitcoin exchanges to consider:

1. Centralized
2. Decentralized

With decentralized exchanges, users keep their assets local, and so there is no need to trust a central authority. At the present time, it is harder for decentralized exchanges to build up liquidity. This means that the trading volume is lower and the bid/ask spread is wider.

Here are couple of resources regarding decentralized exchanges:

1. [0x Protocol for building decentralized exchanges for Ethereum
   assets](https://0xproject.com/faq)
2. [Waves platform DEX - decentralized exchange](https://blog.wavesplatform.com/what-is-waves-dex-7c311d1360a1)
3. https://www.cryptocompare.com/exchanges/guides/what-is-a-decentralized-exchange/

Now, with centralized exchanges, the central authority running the exchange must be trusted. The process of deciding who to trust is less straight forward. Here are some attributes to consider when evaluating a centralized exchange:

- The people running the exchange or company
- The country where the exchange is subject to regulations
- The security practice the exchange uses to protect customer assets
- The insurance policy offered by the exchange
- The history of customer issues at the exchange, reviews etc.
- The transparency the exchange offers
- The communication facilitated by the exchange with its customers

I have put together this YouTube playlist discussing some of these attributes with respect to GDAX, Coinbase's exchange: [GDAX and Coinbase cryptocurrency exchange - Overview](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xr17PqeytCKiCD-TJj89rII)

Comment: @Taemyr I updated with further info: For finding Bitcoin exchanges, check here (exchanges are ordered by volume): https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/btc/markets/USD

Answer (score 0):

I've come to realize over the years it's a good practice if you have a decent amount of value sitting on an exchange and you want to go long..  it's best to take the time to download the blockchain for your investments, Then encrypt the wallet files and backup to multiple places (including a cloud account).

Taking the coin off the exchange gives you a peace of mind and mitigates "impulse trades".

If you are trying to find the best exchange to short a coin, click the coin on coinmarketcap.com and look for the exchange with the most volume.

I prefer Poloniex, Kraken, hitbtc, and liqu
I've lost coin on mtgox, bitfinex, btce

Good luck trading!

Comment: Most of this answer is unrelated to the question, he didn't ask about long term holding best-practises...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/41436)

Comment: @cdecker I think this is an answer - the answer is 'don't put yourself in a position where you need to trust the exchange for long periods of time.'