# How to choose an exchange?

Tags: exchanges

Let's assume you want to exchange traditional currency for Bitcoins and choose to do so through and exchange.

What are the most important factors/features that you should keep into consideration for choosing an exchange?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59612/how-do-i-know-which-exchanges-are-serious-actors/59621#59621

Answer (score 1):

1. Verification time: some exchanges take too much time for verification
2. Verification versus / not verification: some exchanges need verification and others not
3. Fees. In my opinion, you get the lowest fees on binance -> https://www.binance.com/?ref=16821839
4. Time: some exchanges take too much time to withdraw etc.
   here's a guide to choose the best exchange (made by me) -> https://medium.com/@redqop89/trading-guide-for-bitcoin-ethereum-ripple-and-other-cryptocurrencies-6773ab4b6b2